# Select points by lasso in Qt using Geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, geopandas

I'm creating a GUI using Qt for plotting a **geopandas** dataframe conformed by points.
Now I'd like to **subset** the geopandas dataframe by **lasso** some of the plotted points, just like selecting points by lasso in Arcmap.

Does anybody know how can I achieve this?

I've heard about Lasso Selector of `Matplotlib` by I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty light on specifics. What's even the problem you're running into? Do you know how to draw points in a (Py)Qt GUI? Do you know how to select points with geopandas? (This is easily googled: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279670/geopandas-equivalent-to-select-by-location)

Did you actually try the matplotlib lasso selector? This example works interactively: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/lasso_selector_demo_sgskip.html

If you just want to plot and select points, it's likely sufficient. No need for a Qt GUI.

Anyway, if you really need a Qt application... I'm assuming you already have a a GeoDataFrame containing the data, e.g. called `points`.

1. Design something in (Py)Qt which allows drawing a geometry on your plot.
2. Collect the vertices of the drawn geometry.
3. Convert the vertices into a shapely polygon (via `shapely.geometry.Polygon`).
4. Find the points within in the polygon, `points.within(polygon)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer has been been completely useful.
I cannot be more specific because I'm wondering the way I will do it. Hasn't done it yet.